# Does reducing fruit change its composition?

Tags: reduction

I like fresh fruit reductions like cranberry coulis or [lingonberry](https://www.myrecipes.com/recipe/herbed-rack-of-lamb-with-lingonberry-sauce) and huckleberry sauce. But I am worried that I'm not merely evaporating the water, but changing the sauce in other ways.

1. Does simmering a fruit reduction cause anything other than water to evaporate?
2. Does reduction reduce or destroy the vitamins by heat? A comment by [Johnannes_B](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/109507/doesnt-reduction-unnecessarily-waste-resources?noredirect=1#comment175121_109507) mentioned this.

Comment: Previous conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110310/discussion-on-question-by-vast-does-reducing-fruit-change-its-composition). The question is not opinion-based at this point, and it's basically just asking one thing (the two parts are just two ways reduction could remove things).

Answer (score 1):

Any molecules more volatile than water will be evaporating more than water molecules, less volatile molecules will evaporate less than water at the boiling point. This is the basic principle behind distillation.

The heat will for sure be driving chemical changes.

Comment: Should this be moved to chat? IDK. Perhaps the answer is simply yes and yes.

Comment: Hi, we don't allow discussion on nutrition here, so I had to remove the part about that.